# Implement animation for searching in Android

Tags: android, animation

Had been trying to implement a simple animation while one of my process is doing work in the background.

The requirement of animation is to create a ripple effect around a circular image view in the center of screen.

Examples can be seen in Google hangouts video session when there is some growing circle animation around profile circle or in apps like Tinder where it searches for profiles.

I have tried to put some 4 drawables of circles one over other and alter their visibility in a for loop:

```
ImageView one = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ImageView two = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    ImageView three = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    ImageView four = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

    try {
        for(int i=1; i<10; i++){
            one.setVisibility(one.VISIBLE);
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            two.setVisibility(two.VISIBLE);
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            three.setVisibility(three.VISIBLE);
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            four.setVisibility(four.VISIBLE);
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            one.setVisibility(one.INVISIBLE);
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            two.setVisibility(two.INVISIBLE);
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            three.setVisibility(three.INVISIBLE);
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            four.setVisibility(four.INVISIBLE);
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But when I run this, the app is crashing. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is this being executed on a separate thread? If not, you should move it to one as `Thread.sleep()` should **NEVER** be used on the main thread.

With that said, you cannot execute UI related work (ie. `setVisibility()`) off of the main UI thread. To use your current approach, you will need to add a `runOnUiThread()` around each of your `setVisibility()` calls.

If you would rather not do that, you can modify your code to the following:

```
ImageView one = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
ImageView two = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
ImageView three = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
ImageView four = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);


final ImageView images[] = {one, two, three, four};
new Thread() {

    public void run() {

        for(int i=1; i<10; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<images.length; j++) {
                images[i].setAlpha(255);
                images[i].postInvalidate();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            for (int j=0; j<images.length; j++) {
                images[i].setAlpha(0);
                images[i].postInvalidate();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: It is still crashing :( I tried to put it run on ui thread as well but no help - `code` getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               try {
          for(int i=1; i<10; i++){
        one.setVisibility(one.VISIBLE);
        Thread.sleep(1000);

Comment: but then how can I introduce delay between each of these statements. As without the delay I am unable to see any transition, for loop ends instantly.

Comment: Have you tried using my code? I think it is a bit more intuitive to do it with `postInvalidate` because the offloading to the UI thread is taken care of for you. Essentially, the only portion that needs to be offloaded to the UI thread is redrawing the view. Everything else can happen on your background thread. Everything still happens in sequence.

Comment: Sorry! Can you please throw some more light.. because your code does not have run on UI thread. Also, If I use your code which has Thread.sleep(), is crashing the app. I also tried using one.setAlpha(255);                 one.postInvalidate(); without Thread.sleep() inside runOnUiThread but still I see only blank screen because 'for' loop has ended instantly.

Comment: Take a look at my answer now. I have a feeling you were not offloading this portion onto a new thread, so I included that portion as well. I also cleaned up the code a bit to make it easier to add/subtract images in the future.

Comment: I tried this too but it was still crashing. So, I tried this I converted this into a animation and put that explicitly into runOnUiThread() but it was important that sleep was not part of that function. And finally, it is running without crashing. I hope it works smoothly. Anyways, thanks a ton for your help and suggestions. I really appreciate your efforts.